# How safe is "with-silent-modifications" to mask (hide) strings before and after buffer modification?

Tags: replace, elisp-macros

In my `LaTeX` code I want to replace one-line `eqnarray` environments with the `equation` environment. To do that I need to "count" the new-line (`\\`) strings in a region and I also need to ignore some new-line strings that may occur in some math sub-enviroments like `array`, `matrix` etc.

If I have, e.g.:

```latex
\begin{eqnarray}
x+y&=& 1 
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray}
```

I need to ignore the `\\` strings inside the array environment.

To do that I can, temporarily replace these strings with arbitrary strings but I have the downside of the reappearing of them (the arbitrary strings) when i `undo` some changes.

So I tried to use the `with-silent-modification` macro:

```el
(defun latex-one-line-eqnarray-to-equation ()
  (interactive)
    (save-excursion
      (let* ((a (copy-marker (point-min)))
             (z (copy-marker (point-max))))

    (goto-char a)
    (unwind-protect
        (while (search-forward-regexp "\\\\begin{eqnarray}" nil t)
          (save-excursion
            (let ((b (copy-marker (match-beginning 0)))
                  (e (copy-marker (search-forward-regexp 
                                   "\\\\end{eqnarray}" nil t))))

              ;; *LaTeX sub environment line break occultation:*
              (save-restriction
                (narrow-to-region b e)
                (goto-char b)
                (while (search-forward-regexp "\\\\begin{array}" nil t)
                  (save-excursion
                    (let ((i (copy-marker (match-beginning 0)))
                          (f (copy-marker (search-forward-regexp 
                                           "\\\\end{array}" nil t))))

                      (with-silent-modifications
                        (perform-replace "\\\\" "❤❤" nil nil nil 1 nil i f)))))

                (when (= 0 (how-many "\\\\\\\\" b e))
                  (perform-replace "{eqnarray}" 
                                   "{equation}" t nil nil 1 nil b e))))))

      ;; *UNWINDFORMS*
      (with-silent-modifications
        (perform-replace "❤❤" "\\\\" nil nil nil 1 nil a z))))))
```

In this case the trick seems to work because I (temporarily) replace my target string with one of the same length (`\\` with `❤❤`).

***Is it a coincidence? Is it safe to operate this way?***

**Note.** I'd prefer to use some "tex property" to hide my target string to the `how-many` function but I've not been able to find the way to do it.

**Note 2.** I red the `with-silent-modifications` docstring:

> If BODY performs real modifications to the buffer’s text, other
>   than cosmetic ones, undo data may become corrupted.

Comment: `C-h f perform-replace` says: "Don't use this in your own program"

Comment: @Stefan This is not true (complete). The `docstring` says: *Don’t use this in your own program unless you want to query and set the mark just as ‘query-replace’ does.*

Comment: Same difference in the present case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing a string with one of the same length indeed falls within the "cosmetic" description, tho only if that change doesn't additionally affect the output of `syntax-ppss`.

I believe in your case, it should indeed be safe to operate this way.

But the reasons why it's safe are pretty subtle, so it'd be better to find another way to do it.  The only *truly* safe changes to do in `with-silent-modifications` are text-property changes.  So maybe the better option is the following:

- in the loop through `array` env, just add a `within-array-env` text-property over the whole env (without bothering to search for `\\`).
- Instead of calling `how-many`, loop through all the matches of the regexp and check whether they are tagged with the `within-array-env` property: if all of them are, then you can convert to `equation`.
- At the end, remove that `within-array-env`.

Comment: Could "collapsing undo history" be a good idea?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi: I don't see a good reason to want to do that here.

Comment: I mean, if I remove the two `with-silent-modifications` macro instances, could "collapsing undo history" be a good method to let emacs consider all the changes performed by each single the (first) `while` iteration as a single `undo` block?

Comment: It would do that, but it wouldn't solve other cases.  E.g. when there's no eqnarray to be converted, the buffer would still be marked as "modified" because of the other transient modifications.

Comment: Ok, in this case I don't care if the buffer would be marked as modified... I was looking for a method to make `undo` avoid to put back in the buffer my temporary "cosmetic" substitutions.

Comment: Even without amalgamation undo won't put back your cosmetic changes (or rather, it will put them and remove them anyway).  If you fix your misuses of `perform-replace` there won't be any undo-boundary to remove by undo-amalgamation anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90450/discussion-between-gabriele-nicolardi-and-stefan).